# E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable

Tags: php

I'm pretty new with PHP and I'm trying to learn all by myself.

I tried to create a simple form with a simple calc to incorporate on my website but I got this E_Notice. And don't know how to echo the result in the html too.

Someone can help?

Link here: [PHPfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tjf-g9r)

Comment: @Mr.Alien vague? Run F9 on the link, the form explains it itself.

Comment: I would suggest you to share your code here along with the actual warnings/errors with line numbers, as if the link will be dead, your question won't be useful anymore to the future visitors

Comment: You could have mentioned that this notice appears when displaying the form, before it even was submitted. Which is to be expexcted, since `$_POST` is empty on GET requests, and you didn't include an appropriate check (easy to google).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code checks to see if `$_POST['valor-finan']` is set -- if it is, it sets the variable `$valor_finan`. If it IS NOT set, then the variable `$valor_finan` is never created. Then, your code checks to see if it is empty -- it isn't empty, it doesn't even exist.

Instead, you should set the variable to something no matter what, that way it exists in the code. If you get some `$_POST` data, use that data, otherwise provide a default value like false.

`empty` is not the best function to check numeric values. Use `is_numeric` -- a 0 might be acceptable for your application, but `empty` will consider 0 to be... empty. Not good for financial calculations.

Also, you are using globals where you don't need to. The `global` keyword is always bad practice. The `switch` was unnecessary, too.

Here is your code with the corrections in place:

```
$valor_finan = (
    isset($_POST['valor-finan']) ? 
    $_POST['valor-finan'] : false
);
$valor_entrada = (
    isset($_POST['valor-entrada']) ? 
    $_POST['valor-entrada'] : false
);
$numero_parcela = (
    isset($_POST['numero-parcela']) ? 
    $_POST['numero-parcela'] : false
);
function calculaFinanciamento ($valor_finan, $valor_entrada, $numero_parcela) {
    if(
        is_numeric($valor_finan) && 
        is_numeric($valor_entrada) && 
        is_numeric($numero_parcela) 
    ){
            $taxa_percent = 5;
            $valor_parcela_bruto = ($valor_finan - $valor_entrada) / $numero_parcela;
            $valor_percent = ($taxa_percent / 100) * $valor_parcela_bruto;
            $valor_parcela = $valor_parcela_bruto + $valor_percent;
            return $valor_parcela;
    } else {
        return "Por favor preencha os campos, todos são requeridos";
    }
}

echo calculaFinanciamento($valor_finan, $valor_entrada, $numero_parcela);
```

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but why can't I call the echo inside de HTML markup without these errors? http://bit.ly/17o0SQu

Comment: @Carol Pretty much the same problem. The script executes top-to-bottom. So, the code establishing the variables hasn't run yet. Typically, the php code is at the top of the file, at least the part that will deal with getting data from POST or GET.

Comment: @Carol I updated the sample code to show you the correct approach.

Comment: thank you again. These questions seems so silly for you guys but for me is kinda hard.. yet, i hope. :)

Comment: @Carol Bah! I started learning PHP from a book 12 years ago, and I can't stand reading code I wrote even 2 years ago. Everyone should be learning, constantly, and if someone thinks they know it all then they only show their ignorance. Again, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables valor_finan , valor_entrada, numero_parcela have not been set.
Use isset($valor_finan) etc to check if they contain records/have been set or not.